# The IP address of a pod in Kubernetes if it communicates with an external API?

Tags: kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-ingress

Assume I have a pod running in a Kubernetes cluster.

Now this pod wants to interact with an external API.

What IP address does the API "see", when the pod makes a request to the API?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that api refers to Google, what Google sees is your external network IP.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Could you be a little more specific, perhaps with examples? That would be terrific.

Answer (score 0):

What the API sees is the router's public address of your cluster's network.

In most implementation of Kubernetes, the Nodes of your cluster (and by extend your Pods) are within a private network. Therefore they have private IP adresses which cannot be routed through the internet, by definition.

So, when they want to communicate with the internet, they must go through the router of the private network. The router performs Network Address Translation (NAT) to map your Nodes (and Pods) private IPs to a single public IP address, the address of the router.

From the perspective of the internet, the communication appears to be coming from the router's public IP address, not the original private IP address.

When the router receives responses from the internet, it uses the NAT table to send the response to the correct device within the private network.